# 'isOnboardingFinished' is inaccessible due to 'internal' protection level

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I am trying to build expo react native app on ios with `arch -x86_64 yarn ios`

the build is working fine on android , the problem is with ios only

if there are any useful info i could add to the question , please let me know

These are my dependencies relevant to the error:

```
"expo": "~46.0.19"
"react-native": "0.69.6",
```

screenshot of the build error:

[image]

Comment: what are you using to display onboarding in your project?

Comment: I'm not using a package for onboarding ,
the issue is related to expo-dev-launcher "expo-dev-client": "~1.3.1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue was fixed when I ran `expo prebuild` before `arch -x86_64 yarn ios`